# jQuery Slick Slider: How to make a logo ticker slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, ticker

I'm currently using the [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) plugin and don't really want to add another plugin to achieve a Logo Ticker slide effect like seen here [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/examples/ticker). Any idea how to do it with Slick or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Set autoplaySpeed to 0 and cssEase to 'linear' to achieve that effect.

```
$(function() {
    $('.your-class').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 0,
        speed: 1000,
        cssEase:'linear'
    });
});
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ugtdjrjt/

Answer (score 0):

There is an autoplay option at Slick Slider

```
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
});
```

Is that maybe already everything you want?

Comment: No, it should scroll constantly like in the bxSlider demo.

Comment: Thats to fast and there is no option to make it slower :(